# Disable URL Link in a Table if it's older than the Browsers current time

Tags: php, html, css

I hope someone can help me out here. I'm new to the world of web dev and need help disabling the link in my table if the data in my row is older than the current time.

My table looks like the following:

```
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Time'] . "</td>";
echo "<td> <a href=". $row['URL'] ."> Link</a></td>";
    
echo "</tr>";
}
```

If for example the current time is 17:00 and my time column has a row which contains an entry of 13:00 i want to disable the link but keep the row visible.

Any advice on how to do this would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far - for example what php functions to get the current time have you tried? And is the time in the $row entry exactly of this 13:00 form?

Comment: Hi - I haven't tried anything as i wouldn't know where to start - hence asking for help. To confirm, yes - the time is displayed in a 24 hr format - 17:00 as an example.

Comment: Hi, 'where to start' is probably to search for something like 'PHP function to get the current time'.

Answer (score -1):

Heres an example

```
<?php
$post_date = $row['Time'];
$current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $current_date;
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Time'] . "</td>";
if ($post_date < $current_date){
    // the post_date is older
    echo "<td> <a href=". $row['URL'] ."> Link</a></td>";
}

echo "</tr>";
?>
```

Comment: Just answer the question, i need that information to help you

Comment: HI - The time is in a 24hr format; 17:00 for example. There's no date in the field.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the suggestion. Bearing in mind that it's rows with a TIME that's older than the current time which i need to disable, how will your code work when it clearly states the date "$current_date = date("Y-m-d");". To clarify, if the current time is 19:00 and a row contains a time of 15:00 - i want the URL to be disabled.

Comment: I updated the answer to check the hours minutes and seconds too

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works!! I made a small change to just obtain the time ("H:i") and i put an ELSE in to put a non HREF link for times which have passed. Thanks again.

Comment: Have fun coding your project!